# Is there a way to send the calendar appointments from the standard android google calendar to another (android) app?

Tags: android

I'd like to show only the appointment content within the other app. The other app does not have any calendar functions.

Comment: If the other app "does not have any calendar functions", then how do you expect to "show... the appointment content" in that other app?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch calendar data from the Android calendar provider and then present it or copy it in your app, you can find more info and examples on the calendar provider here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

You will also need proper permission in particular:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```